# Cumulative sum of a dataframe column with restart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to perform the following function on a dataframe.

Calculate the cumulative sum of a column, notice:

1. It looks at the previous index only, not including the current one, e.g. the very first one will be zero as there is no previous data to look at.
2. When it doesn't cumulate, e.g the increment is zero, it restarts the count.

   ```
         Number  Cumulative
      0       1           0
      1       1           1
      2       1           2
      3       0           3
      4       0           0
      5       1           0
      6       1           1
      7       0           2
   ```

I know there is an expanding function, but it doesnt restart when it sees zero

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this works by making groups according to whether the previous row was 0, then getting the cumulative count:

```
>>> df
   Number
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       0
5       1
6       1
7       0

df['Cumulative'] = df.groupby(df.Number.shift().eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()

>>> df
   Number  Cumulative
0       1           0
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       0           3
4       0           0
5       1           0
6       1           1
7       0           2
```

Alternatively, if it really is `cumsum` you want, then apply cumsum with the same grouping as above, and shift it 1 down:

```
df['Cumulative '] = df.groupby(df.Number.eq(0).cumsum()).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)
>>> df
   Number  Cumulative 
0       1          0.0
1       1          1.0
2       1          2.0
3       0          3.0
4       0          0.0
5       1          0.0
6       1          1.0
7       0          2.0
```

Comment: From the example of pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount (pandas 0.23.4 documentation), why the result of df.groupby('A').cumcount() is 0 1 2 0 1 3? why 3 at the end?

Comment: Because that's the 4th row with `a` in column `A` (and the `cumcount` starts at 0). This is why you can just groupby `Number` in your case, because you're trying to reset the counter when 0 is encountered in the previous row

Comment: so why in the solution you gave me, on the 6th row, it doesn't show 4, and 7th shows 5?

Comment: Because I interpreted your question as wanting to reset when 0 was encountered, so I grouped by when 0 was encountered (resetting the cumulative count)

Comment: Understand! so if i extend the question (for learning), I would like to get another column which the result is 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 2, basically I want the max number in the sub cumulation, or the number before 0.